# Proving a linear transform is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Prove that A is injective iff
                           $\{v \in V :Av=0\}=\{0\}$
I read that a linear transform is injective iff the kernel of the function is $0$, but I am supposed to use the fact that for all $a,b \in V$, $A(a+b)=A(a)+A(b)$. Is this any different than proving a function is injective by using the implication "If $f(x)=f(y)$,then $x=y$"?

Comment: I think you mean "for all $a,b \in V$".  And yes, a linear map is a type of function, so proving injectivity comes down to showing $Ax = Ay$ implies $x=y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not any different than proving a function is injective since linear mappings are in fact functions as the name suggests. However linear maps have the restricted linear structure that general functions do not have. It is for this reason that we often consider linear maps as general results are possible; few general results hold for arbitrary maps. This allows us to easily prove injectivity.

Suppose you have that $A$ is injective. Then we want to conclude that the kernel of $A$ is $0$. Suppose $x\in\ker A$, then $A(x) = 0$. However we know that $A(0) = 0$ since $A$ is linear. Since $A$ is injective and $A(x) = A(0)$, we must conclude that $x = 0$.

Can you handle the other direction? Here's a hint: suppose $x,y\in V$ and $Ax = Ay$, then $A(x-y) = 0$ by making use of linearity.

Comment: So $A(x-y)=A(x)-A(y)=0$ which means $A(x)=A(y)$ so we can conclude that  if $A(x)=A(y)$ then $x=y$?

Comment: @Cameron: The last hint is a little confusing. You should start by saying that if $Ax=Ay$ for $x,y\in\color{red}V$, then $0=Ax-Ay=A(x-y)$, and this shows that $x-y\in\text{ker}(A)=\{0\}$. Thus, $x=y$.

Comment: @sranthrop Wow I don't know how I did that. You're totally right.

Comment: Oh, no problem   :)

Comment: Thank you Cameran and sranthrop. I now understand more about how to prove that a linear map is injective using linearity.

Comment: @user3699546 Glad to help and glad you understand :)